# How run an Access 2007 module in VB6?

Tags: ms-access, vba, vb6, ms-access-2007

I have created a module in access 2007 that will update linked tables, but I wanted to run this module from vb6. I have tried this code from Microsoft, but it didnt work.

```
      Sub AccessTest1()
      Dim A As Object

      Set A = CreateObject("Access.Application")
      A.Visible = False

      A.OpenCurrentDatabase (App.Path & "/DataBase/acc.accdb")

      A.DoCmd.RunMacro "RefreshLinks"

   End Sub
```

What I am aiming to do, is to allow my program to update all linked tables to new links, in case the program has been used on other computer

In case you want to take a look at the module program, here it is:

```
Sub CreateLinkedJetTable()
Dim cat As ADOX.Catalog
Dim tbl As ADOX.Table

Set cat = New ADOX.Catalog

' Open the catalog.
cat.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection

Set tbl = New ADOX.Table

' Create the new table.
tbl.Name = "Companies"
Set tbl.ParentCatalog = cat

' Set the properties to create the link.
tbl.Properties("Jet OLEDB:Link Datasource") = CurrentProject.Path & "/db3.mdb"
tbl.Properties("Jet OLEDB:Remote Table Name") = "Companies"
tbl.Properties("Jet OLEDB:Create Link") = True

' To link a table with a database password set the Link Provider String
' tbl.Properties("Jet OLEDB:Link Provider String") = "MS Access;PWD=Admin;"

' Append the table to the tables collection.
cat.Tables.Append tbl
Set cat = Nothing

End Sub

Sub RefreshLinks()
Dim cat As ADOX.Catalog
Dim tbl As ADOX.Table

Set cat = New ADOX.Catalog

' Open the catalog.
cat.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection

Set tbl = New ADOX.Table

For Each tbl In cat.Tables
' Verify that the table is a linked table.
    If tbl.Type = "LINK" Then
        tbl.Properties("Jet OLEDB:Link Datasource") = CurrentProject.Path & "/db3.mdb"
' To refresh a linked table with a database password set the Link Provider String
'tbl.Properties("Jet OLEDB:Link Provider String") = "MS Access;PWD=Admin;"
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: How did it not work?  Without that, any answer is just a guess.

Comment: Do you have a macro named "RefreshLinks"?

Comment: @David-W-Fenton After long time of search i found out that i dont have a marco and to get the marco i had to call the function this question is solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake here is that all of the functions are subs, to make the Macro run i have to either do one of the following

Change each `sub` into `Public Function` or create a function that calls both sub example

```
public function Refresh()
  RefreshLinked
end Function`
```

and then create a Marco and in Action look for Run code, and look up for the function and everything well work fine

Thanks people